# Table text getting overlapped in dynamically generated <table> - Javascript jquery.quickflip.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlap

[image: Over Written text on a table]

Hello guys, i am trying to generate a table dynamically using tabs generated with the help of jquery.quickflip.js, the problem is when i switch over from one tab to another tab some times i notice the text getting overwritten with value from previous tab. Below is a snippet from my for loop which i use to generate this table. Please help.

```
for (var i = 0, len = mydata.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (mydata[i].Apppool != "srvstat_apppool") {
        content += '<tr><td> ' + mydata[i].Pid + ' </td> <td> ' + mydata[i].Apppool + ' </td><td> ' + Math.round(mydata[i].Usage); + ' </td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: we need to see more code. show us your html, and the block of code that inserts/appends the dynamic data

Answer (score 0):

I have inspected the CSS of the plugin. It seems

```
position: relative;
```

is the causing the contents of table cells to overlap, please try the following CSS override [assuming your table or cells are having one of the following classes]....

```
.flipColLeft, .flipColRight, .quickFlipPanel
 {
    position:static;
 }
```

If the flip functionality is getting affected by the above override, please wrap the contents of the table cell in a div.

Hope it helps!